# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help as i've spent all day trying to fix this. I installed the latest XAMPP and now i can't connect to mysql from terminal.I checked my .profile file and the PATH seems ok. Does anyone know whats happened and what's the solution?

PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
export PATH

THIS IS A PROGRAMMING QUESTION AS I'M A PHP DEVELOPER TRYING TO DO MY JOB!

Thankyou soo much in advance;-)

UPDATE: the solution was to update the .bash_profile with (as well as the .profile file)

PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
export PATH

spent the whole day trying to work this out so i hope this helps anyone in the same position ;-)
http://www.jroller.com/jnicho02/entry/setting_up_xampp_on_the (GOOD LINK)

Comment: check your my.cnf for the path of mysql.sock and that your daemon is running (you might better want to switch over to serverfault.com with this)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the MySQL daemon. Is it running? Try typing on the command line: `ps -u mysql` and see if that gives any results.

Comment: this is the output i got 
UID   PID TTY           TIME CMD
Any ideas?

Comment: Means it's not running. Still this is more of a serverfault question than a stackoverflow one.

Answer (score 1):

@amphetamachine is right - you need to do something like this:

```
[root@vps ~]# service mysqld start
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because MySQL is installed but not yet running.

Follow step2 and step6 in the link below
http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.in/2009/08/install-mysql-on-mac-os-x.html