# MYSQL not running on Ubuntu OS - Error 2002

Tags: mysql, database-connection, ubuntu-10.04

I am a novice to mysql DB. I am trying to run the MYSQL Server on Ubuntu 10.04. Through Synaptic Package Manager I am have installed the mysql version: mysql-client-5.1

I wonder that how was the database password set for the mysql-client software that I installed through the above way.It would be nice if you could enlighten me on this.

When I tried running this database, I encountered the error given below:

```
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:/var/lib$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:/var/lib$
```

I referred to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032886/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysq) posted by another user. I didn't find a solution through the proposed answers.

For instance when I tried the solutions posted for the similar question I got the following:

```
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:/var/lib$ service start mysqld
start: unrecognized service
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:/var/lib$ ps -u mysql
ERROR: User name does not exist.
********* simple selection *********  ********* selection by list *********
-A all processes                      -C by command name
-N negate selection                   -G by real group ID (supports names)
-a all w/ tty except session leaders  -U by real user ID (supports names)
-d all except session leaders         -g by session OR by effective group name
-e all processes                      -p by process ID
T  all processes on this terminal     -s processes in the sessions given
a  all w/ tty, including other users  -t by tty
g  OBSOLETE -- DO NOT USE             -u by effective user ID (supports names)
r  only running processes             U  processes for specified users
x  processes w/o controlling ttys     t  by tty
*********** output format **********  *********** long options ***********
-o,o user-defined  -f full            --Group --User --pid --cols --ppid
-j,j job control   s  signal          --group --user --sid --rows --info
-O,O preloaded -o  v  virtual memory  --cumulative --format --deselect
-l,l long          u  user-oriented   --sort --tty --forest --version
-F   extra full    X  registers       --heading --no-heading --context
                    ********* misc options *********
-V,V  show version      L  list format codes  f  ASCII art forest
-m,m,-L,-T,H  threads   S  children in sum    -y change -l format
-M,Z  security data     c  true command name  -c scheduling class
-w,w  wide output       n  numeric WCHAN,UID  -H process hierarchy
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:/var/lib$ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:/var/lib$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I even tried referring to http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,27769,84713#msg-84713 but couldn't find anything useful.

Please let me know how I could tackle this error.

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mohnish@mohnish-laptop:/var/lib$ service mysqld start
> ```

looks like you did not install the mysql server package

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

should help

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the exact command I needed to use to get the server installed. I was not able to find this in the synaptic manager.. I wonder why.. but anyways the terminal did the job for me..

Answer (score 2):

This really belongs on serverfault.

Anyway, you installed the mysql-client package but what you need is the mysql-server package. The client is just the command-line client, while the server is what runs the server itself.

After installing it on Ubuntu, you can start and stop it as root via:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer & the extra info... I shall be more careful next time while posting questions..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands

```
dpkg -l mysql* | grep ii | awk '{ print $2 }' | sudo xargs apt-get remove --purge -y
```

&&

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```