# get database from xampp (not via phpmyadmin)

Tags: database, xampp, backup

I would like to ask, if it is possible to get my database from an offline (not functioning) xampp ?

You see, I have backed up my database earlier but I am not sure whether there are all the data I need now and the DB is pretty big (like 50 tables). I wanted to go for a local implementation of apache, mysql and PHP for my web applications. So I have reinstalled mysql and want to use my own local apache server instead of xampp.

I would like to know where can I find some .sql or something that is stored in xampp that could be otherwise accessible via the phpmyadmin? Is it even possible? I have scrolled through the xampp folder and tried to figure out where it can be, but didnt find anything though.

Thanks for help.

EDIT

I am on a mac running mavericks.

Comment: Database are resides in C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\data.Are you mean it??

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but it throws an error when I want to use it: **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

Comment: go through this..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032886/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mys

Comment: Nope, thats not working, I have my own mysql running already.

Answer (score 0):

First go to localhost/phpmyadmin and create a database as before you have. Then import your database file through browse. 
If your database name exmaple.sql then create database name will be example and import example.sql

Comment: I cant do that I dont have the xampp running anymore